# How to present gallery like a network using HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, and I need to make this kind of presentation below!
So, how can I do that easy way, and with html, css or how ?

[image: Showing Images inside the website like this plan]
Thanks !

Comment: Amm... Like what? What logic? Currently I can tell you: `.gallery{background: url('/path/to/question-image.png') no-repeat center center}`

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking care, i didn't type any code, and still have no good idea how to start applying this, so is that the right place for my question ?

Comment: First one: CSS grid layout in 1 year. Both: in SVG I guess

Comment: Do u mean, i need to create it using SVG with illustrator ?

Comment: As suggested before you need to do it with SVG but if you want to make it easy and manageable at run time then you should go for the https://d3js.org/ as that will be the best option to create different type of linked network easily implementing some algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The first example would be simpler, using a CSS grid system and then using pseudo elements on boxes to add the connecting lines between them like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box connect-down">box 1</div>
  <div class="box connect-left">box 2</div>
  <div class="box connect-up">box 3</div>
  <div class="box connect-right">box 4</div>
</div>
```

The second example would be much harder, I'd suggest using absolute positioning to place the items at specific locations, and maybe separate divs for the connecting lines using the transform rotate to place them

```
<div class="box" style="position:absolute;top:40px;left:30px;">box 1</div>
<div class="connector" style="width:2px;background:grey;height:200px;transform:rotate(40deg)"></div>
```

There are many thumbnail image galleries out there which might be better to download and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

implementing first presentation will be much easier as compared to other by using bootstrap grid system. however second is also possible to implement with css. but it will require more css for responsive design..!